# Android voice navigation support for limb impaired users and rainy weather

Tags: screen, accessibility, weather, voice

I was wondering whether there is any support or whether Android had any plans to support using Android under the rain (for instance, also in situations where an umbrella may not be enough because of the wind. Under these scenarios, the screen, gets all wet, and the rain drops activate touch, on the screen, getting the phone to respond to the pattern of rain drops that touches the screen, in a manner that becomes out of control of the finger swipes).

Because of this, I thought it would be nice if it were possible to configure the phone to have the screen become unresponsive to both finger and rain touch (impossible to make these separate), and, whether, at the same time, it would be possible (via Android support), to activate screen touches and swipes or even interact in a completely separate but intuitive manner using a headset (microphone and earpieces) attached to the phone via the headset input (because rain could interfere with voice as well, as it makes some noise as it taps on the screen... but the screen remains still largely viewable).

The voice input could be similar to TalkBack, but, instead of navigating with finger swipes, you could navigate (and enter input) via voice.

I think this would be nice.

Does Android support this?

Would anyone be willing to implement such rainy weather support in Android?

I think it would also be useful for people lacking arms or hands or who had these paralyzed but could still use voice to navigate and enter input into their phone.

When will this behavior be implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: Your social activism is to be commended, since you show a history of these questions here. This site deals mostly with how to do things that exist in some form of hardware or software implemented vs. "How to make companies implement features serving a missing or particular need". It is unlikely decision makers for hardware or software of this need are here to answer. The "Why" and the "When" aspects of your question(s) are not the focus of this Q&A site. Your questions would drive a good editorial or socially-focused magazine article in the proper forum.